# get table with default values if no row present from StoredProcedure

Tags: objective-c, sql-server

I have iPhone APP which was released today. Data for the app is coming from Database. While testing I noticed for one of the SPs which returns Dataset having 4 tables from Table to Table3. Table3 some time does not exist depending on the `WHERE` claus for some of the Client. Inside the app I have assumed it is present so result I am getting is in the for of dictionary of array. I am directly checking for ObjectATIndex. When table does not return condition fail and App crash.

Since App released today itself I cannot change code as of now.
Can I send some default values inside table.

Suppose my query for the table is

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================            
-- Author:  <Author,,Name>            
-- ALTER date: <ALTER Date,,>            
-- Description: <Description,,>            
-- =============================================            
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[_spGetEmpList]                  
 @strComCode as varchar(50),
 @iDepID as INT,
 @strType AS varchar(20)

AS            
BEGIN            
 DECLARE @bNameOrder as bit  

 SET NOCOUNT ON;  
 SELECT  @bNameOrder = dbo.svnGetSetupOption(@iDepID,
                                            'LastNamePreceedsFirstName',
                                            @strComCode)
 IF ( @bNameOrder IS NULL )
    SET @bNameOrder = 0

IF(@strType = 'Emp')
BEGIN

    --0**************************************            
     SELECT EmpID AS ResourceID, EmpNumber          
     FROM Emuloyeetbl
        WHERE Emuloyeetbl.IsActive = 1 AND DepID = @iDepID  
     ORDER BY EmpFName

     --1**************************************
     SELECT DepartmentName
     FROM tblDepartment
     WHERE IsActive = 1

     --2**************************************
     SELECT OptionValue AS EmpRole
     FROM EmpRole
     WHERE OptionName = 'EmployeeRole' AND DepID = @iDepID AND IsActive = 1

     --3**************************************

    Select EmployeeFirstName + ' '+EmplouyeeLastName as EmpName 
    from EmpTable
    Where DepID = @iDepID AND EmpSalary < 10
END           

END
```

Above query does not return any rows, but inside my app I am checking for table(I assumed table will be present), is there any way I can check if row 
exist or not if not then send some empty value for EmpName, at least app will not Crach.....

Comment: On the positive side, I think it can be fixed but please post full SP, your description is hard to follow. You may be mixing up terminology with recordset and table.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: i have edited Question..

Comment: for the simple query that you have I would recommend the answer that @Joe C has provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think this is a good solution overall.  Seeing that you are stuck, maybe this will work for you.

```
    Create Table #EmpTable (EmployeeFirstName Varchar(8000), EmployeeLastName Varchar(8000), EmpSalary Decimal(15,2))
    Insert #EmpTable Values ('Jill', 'Jacobs', 20000)
    Insert #EmpTable Values ('Joe', 'Johnson', 60000)
```

The query looks like this:

```
If Exists(Select null from #EmpTable Where EmpSalary < @Filter)
        Select EmployeeFirstName + ' '+EmployeeLastName as EmpName from #EmpTable Where EmpSalary < @Filter
        Else
        Select '' as EmpName 


-- If looking for less than 10 a blank row is returned.    
    Declare @Filter Decimal = 10
    If Exists(Select null from #EmpTable Where EmpSalary < @Filter)
    Select EmployeeFirstName + ' '+EmployeeLastName as EmpName from #EmpTable Where EmpSalary < @Filter
    Else
    Select '' as EmpName 

-- This returns the record for Jill Jacobs    
   Declare @Filter Decimal = 30000
   If Exists(Select null from #EmpTable Where EmpSalary < @Filter)
   Select EmployeeFirstName + ' '+EmployeeLastName as EmpName from #EmpTable Where EmpSalary < @Filter
   Else
   Select '' as EmpName
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative answer with [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms175972.aspx):

```
CREATE TABLE EmpTable( EmployeeFirstName VARCHAR( 10 ), EmplouyeeLastName VARCHAR( 10 ), EmpSalary INT )
INSERT INTO EmpTable
VALUES
( 'John', 'Smith', 9 ),
( 'Bob', 'Smith', 11 )

DECLARE @MaxSalary INT
SET @MaxSalary = 7

;WITH EmpTable2 (EmpName)
AS
(
    SELECT EmployeeFirstName + ' '+EmplouyeeLastName as EmpName
    FROM EmpTable
    WHERE EmpSalary < @MaxSalary
)
SELECT *
FROM EmpTable2
/* Add Dummy row when no records have been returned by CTE */
UNION ALL
SELECT 'None' AS EmpName
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM EmpTable2 )
```

The above code puts a CTE around your original query. The part following `UNION ALL` conditionally adds a "Dummy" row if no records have been returned by CTE.

Another way:

```
SELECT EmpName
FROM
    ( SELECT EmpName, COUNT(*) OVER() AS Cnt
    FROM
        ( SELECT EmployeeFirstName + ' ' + EmplouyeeLastName AS EmpName
        FROM EmpTable
        WHERE EmpSalary < @MaxSalary
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'None' AS EmpName
         ) AS a
    ) AS b
WHERE ( Cnt > 1 AND EmpName != 'None' ) OR Cnt = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

i have not created any table, but as Joe C mentioned i have used If Exists.

simple way:

```
IF EXISTS( Select EmployeeFirstName + ' '+EmplouyeeLastName as EmpName 
    from EmpTable
    Where DepID = @iDepID AND EmpSalary < 10)
     BEGIN
         Select EmployeeFirstName + ' '+EmplouyeeLastName as EmpName 
         from EmpTable
         Where DepID = @iDepID AND EmpSalary < 10
        ORDER BY EmpName
     END
     ELSE
     BEGIN
        SELECT '' AS EmpName
     END
```

Thank you Joe C for quick help.

Comment: Please consider marking Joe C's answer as accepted (big "tick symbol") next to his question